# How to validate all controls within knockout foreach loop?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, observablecollection

**Observable Array:**

```
var array=[
{List:[{Id:1,Name:'abc'}{Id:2,Name:'abc'}],UtilityId:0,AnnualUsage:'',Price:,Adder:},
{List:[{Id:1,Name:'abc'}{Id:2,Name:'abc'}],UtilityId:0,AnnualUsage:'',Price:,Adder:},
{List:[{Id:1,Name:'abc'}{Id:2,Name:'abc'}],UtilityId:0,AnnualUsage:'',Price:,Adder:}
]
```

**Knockout Binding:**

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: NomatchAccounts.Accounts">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select data-bind="options: Utility,value:UtilityId, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id',optionsCaption:'Choose Utiity..'"
                class="form-control"></select>
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text:AccountNumber"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value:Meter" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control" data-bind="value:AnnualUsage" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control" data-bind="value:Price" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control" data-bind="value:Adder" />
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text:AdderProvided"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

I want to validate all text boxes, Dropdown. Can any one suggest me what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onfocusout Event.

```
<input type="text" onfocusout="myFunction()">
```

Anytime the user have new input, it will call myFunction() and pass in user's new input to perform validation.

Or you can use event binding

```
<div data-bind="event: { mouseover: enableDetails, mouseout: disableDetails }">
```

which can trigger a validation event defined in the view model base on events such as keypress, mouseover or mouseout.

Here is the link for your reference!
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html